# Error: cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

Im just learning how to code in Java, and I'm running into an error.

The line: "wage += (overtimeHours * basePay * 1.5);" if giving me some problems. The exact error is:

```
overtimeHours cannot be resolved to a variable
```

However, I have created the variable above with this line:

```
int overtimeHours = hours - 40;
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

```
public class base_pay {


// create two methods in the base_pay class
// first method is pay, the second is main() to run the program

public static void pay(double basePay, int hours) {

    if (basePay < 8.0) {
        System.out.println("You must be paid at least $8.00/hr");
    } else if (hours > 60) {
        System.out.println("You cannot work more than 60 hr pr week");
    } else {
        // define what overtime is here
        int overtime = 0;
        if (hours > 40) {
            int overtimeHours = hours - 40;
            hours = 40; // Because anything over 40 is overtime .. if overtime was 50 hours than use 50
        }
        double wage = basePay*hours;
        wage += (overtimeHours * basePay * 1.5);
        System.out.println("Your total pay is: " + wage);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // going to run pay above, and see what happens
    pay(8.5, 45);
}

}
```

---

Answered by own question. I defined the variable twice.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out as soon as I posted it. I defined the variable twice with "int" ... so I had to remove that.